# From WooCommerce order items, create array of product IDs and quantities

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I am trying to send woocommerce order information to an external api. I am using the following function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_api', 10, 2 );
function send_order_to_api( $order_id, $order ){
// api code here
}
```

The API wants to receive my data in the following format:

```
$incoming_order = [
    'spot_id'   => 1,
    'phone'     => '+0000000000',
    'products'  => [
        [
            'product_id' => 1,
            'count'      => 9
        ],
    ],
];
```

I know I need to get my woocommerce product information like this for example:

```
$order->get_items();
```

and I know I need to turn it into a loop like this:

```
$order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach( $order_items as $product ) {
}
```

But this is where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, to get for each product its ID and the quantity in a correct formatted array:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_api', 10, 2 );
function send_order_to_api( $order_id, $order ){
    $products = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through order line items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the product object

        $products[] = array( 
            'product_id' => $product->get_id(), // product ID
            'count'      => $item->get_quantity(), // product quantity
        );
    }

    $incoming_order = [
        'spot_id'   => 1, // ?
        'phone'     => $order->get_billing_phone(), // The billing phone
        'products'  => $products, // Here we set the correct formatted products array
    ];

    // HERE, your API Code …
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I just want to give you a HUGE thanx for helping me with this. This worked 100%.